# How do I power park?

Tags: burnout-paradise

I've seen achievements, statistics and even the in game radio host mention "Power Parking", but nowhere have I actually found instructions on how do it. I have found carparks, and have launched myself off some of the roofs, but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with Power Parking.

So how do you power park, and how is it scored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power parking is like what you see in the movies. You have to be driving and then E-brake and turn into a spot between two cars. I don't know exactly how it is scored but it is related to the distance between you and the cars you are between, the angle that you turned in from and I think how far away you are from the curb probably. It is essentially scoring a rgular parallel park, just with more awesome attached.

Example video: